# Combinatorial argument for this problem:

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Problem: find : $\sum_{r=0}^{21}\binom{42+r}{42}*\binom{42-r}{21}$ ,is there a combinatorial argument for this summation? My progress i realized that sum of upper terms in binomial is constant equal to 84 : so i thought of somehow distributing 84 items in such a manner that 42 gets some and 21 are given with some restrictions but that doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a change of index $j=r+43$ to rewrite your sum as
$$\sum_{j=43}^{64}\binom{j-1}{42}\binom{85-j}{64-43},$$
which you can combinatorially prove is $$\binom{85}{64}$$
by counting the $64$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,85\}$ according to the $43$rd smallest element.